# How to multiply 2 ArrayLists together?

Tags: java, file, multidimensional-array, arraylist

My question is, how can I multiply two ArrayList(s) together? What I am trying to do is import two separate files (which contain 2d arrays) and put them into separate arraylists. From there I am trying to multiply these two array lists together and then have my output file be a 2d array of the the product of the inputted 2d arrays. In Short, I have two input files (each file is a separate two dimensional array) and I must take these two input files, and multiply them together. My output file should be a single 2d array.

So far my code looks like:

```
package Matrix;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {

public static void multiply(File input_file1, File input_file2, File output_file) {



    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input_file1);
        PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output_file);
        ArrayList<Integer> file1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()){
            file1.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
        scanner.close();
        printer.close();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input_file1);
        PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output_file);
        ArrayList<Integer> file2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()){
            file2.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
        scanner.close();
        printer.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the specific *problem* is that you're having. How to do matrix multiplication? How to create the "2D" arrays? Seeing as how this is some sort of assignment, I think you should work at it a little longer.

Comment: How should it multiply? Give a little example. But also you've done nothing but load the files, with duplicate code, so try writing a function to load a single file into a single array and call it twice.

Comment: @DaveNewton It's tricky to explain, but in other words, I have 2 files going into the program(input) and one file coming out(output), each file contains a matrix, i have to take the product of the two matrices and store them into my output file.

Comment: @MaxBolin Additionally you may want to consider making your program more modular.  i.e. have a method that reads in the file, perhaps use a helper to change `ArrayList` to a `2d array` and then a method to multiply.

Answer (score 0):

```
//method that returns a double 2d matrix and takes two 2d matrices as parameters
public static double[][] multiply(double[][] A, double[][] B) {
        //make sure the matrices are the same size
        int mA = A.length;
        int nA = A[0].length;
        int mB = B.length;
        int nB = B[0].length;
        if (nA != mB) throw new RuntimeException("Matices are not the same");
        //create a new matrix to hold answer
        double[][] C = new double[mA][nB];

        //loop and multiply
        for (int i = 0; i < mA; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nB; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < nA; k++)
                    C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
        return C;
    }
```

Helper method to convert from `ArrayList` to `Array`

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
// populate this list here
//more code

// convert to an array of ArrayLists
ArrayList<String[]> tempList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (ArrayList<String> stringList : mainList){
    tempList.add((String[])stringList.toArray());
}

//Convert to array of arrays - 2D array
String [][]list = (String[][])tempList.toArray();
```

The steps for your algorithm would basically be:

1. Open a file
2. Read into an arrayList
3. Use helper method to convert to 2d array
4. Repeat 1-3 on other file
5. Pass in two 2d arrays to multiplication method
6. Do a happy dance

Comment: This is how I would normally do it, however, my 2d arrays are coming in as "input files", what I am trying to figure out is if i can take those inputs, store them into array lists, and multiply them together. Is it possible to go straight from a File to a 2d array? If so, that makes it somewhat less complicated.

Comment: @MaxBolin Please see my other comment, but, I would read in the file and then use a helper method to convert to a 2d array.  If this is the case the question should really be ammended to "convert arraylist to 2d array"